# How to get the subgraph hash once compiled and deployed?

Tags: hash, the-graph, subgraph

I have a `graph-node` running in a EC2 instance. The subgraph has been compiled, created and deployed already and it is running with no issues.

I want to query its status by running the following command:

```
{ indexingStatuses(subgraphs:["subgraph_hash"])
  { 
    subgraph 
  } 
}
```

How do I get the `subgraph_hash` once it's been deployed?

Answer (score 0):

```
graph status --node https://api.thegraph.com/index-node/ <DEPLOYED_SUBGRAPH_NAME>
```

This should work for what you're doing - should output something like this

```
----------
Subgraph           Subgraph hash
----------
subgraph-name     0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef
----------
```

Comment: Where are you executing that command? 

I get `Error: command status not found` and if I check the `graph` command, there is no `status` option.

Comment: `COMMANDS
  add      Adds a new datasource to a subgraph.

  auth     Sets the deploy key to use when deploying to a Graph node.

  build    Builds a subgraph and (optionally) uploads it to IPFS.

  codegen  Generates AssemblyScript types for a subgraph.

  create   Registers a subgraph name

  deploy   Deploys a subgraph to a Graph node.

  init     Creates a new subgraph with basic scaffolding.

  local    Runs local tests against a Graph Node environment (using Ganache by default).
  
remove   Unregisters a subgraph name

  test     Runs rust binary for subgraph testing.`

Comment: You can use https://thegraph.com/studio/ or the CLI

Comment: My subgraph is not deployed to the studio and, again, `graph-cli` does not have `status` command: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphprotocol/graph-cli